# JS conditions not working with string

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-statements

I'm just doing elementary condition. And this condition passed. How?

#### Javascript

```
var colname = $(this).data('name');
if ( colname == "price" ) {
     $(this).html(parseInt(value));
}
```

#### HTML

```
<span class="editable editable-click" data-type="text" data-pk="27" data-name="autosmo_id" data-url="/manage/action/"> 70</span>
```

http://joxi.net/xAeObPDsn3Bkmy.jpg - example in debugger.

Comment: 1. colname NOT equals price.

Comment: post the related html please

Comment: <span class="editable editable-click" data-type="text" data-pk="27" data-name="autosmo_id" data-url="/manage/action/"> 70</span>

Comment: try console log $(this); use === instead of == in if statement

Comment: misher, in $(this) original object. I tried replace == and === Not working(

Comment: We can't see the reference to `$(this)`

Comment: Link with screenshot which above by link. It show $(this) and colname variable.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that the code that you see in the debugger is _actually_ the code that the browser executes? For example, if you are using source maps (to debug minified code), then the code displayed in the debugger can be different to what is actually executed.

Comment: can you add the markup and js code,to understand the context if do the same thing if condition is not getting ex3ecuted

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Solution: Restart Firefox browser.

Thanks to all.